# Calling various methods of a controller from the loader

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, controller, loader

I am trying to build a loader to load various controller with their methods (as needed) within a controller.  I sketched out a simple code on my home controller to call the LeftController (now a dummy controller but I intend to use this controller as menu).

```
require 'controller/LeftController.php';
$LeftController = new LeftController();
$LeftController->index();
```

This works within the HomeController. It loads the LeftController controller and displays the method index().

Basing my Loader on the above code this is what I have done till now

```
class Loader
{

    public function controller($controller)
    {
        $file = 'controller/' . $controller . '.php';
        $class = $controller;

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            require($file); // require 'controller/LeftController.php';
            $controller = new $class(); //$LeftController = new LeftController();

            var_dump($controller);
        }
    }
}
```

This works too and the controller is instantiated. I see result using the var_dump().

Now, I need to call the method, as we see at the top most code `$LeftController->index();` but on the Loader class this time.

One way of doing this is if I add `$controller->index()` right after the `$controller = new $class();` but this will always call the index() method of the controller.

How do I code this method part as such that I can call any method associated with the controller and not just the index().

Comment: This is **way** too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a method argument with your controller:

```
public function controller($controller, $method)
```

and then call it on your newly created object:

```
$controller->$method()
```

---

**However**,

it seems you are trying to reinvent the wheel. The part where you verify if a files exists,  include it and instantiate the class, is called [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

The code could look like this:

```
public function controller($controller, $method)
{
    $instance = new $controller();
    return $instance->$method();
}
```

While the autoloading part makes use of [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to manage finding and including files.

> The spl_autoload_register() function registers any number of autoloaders, enabling for classes and interfaces to be automatically loaded if they are currently not defined.

So you can use the code you already have, and abstract it from the action of instantiating the class:

```
spl_autoload_register(function autoloader($controller) {
    $file = 'controller/' . $controller . '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) { require($file); }
});
```